# Ellipse of minimum area, circumscribing n circles

Tags: sequences-and-series, geometry, conic-sections

I was solving a problem based on ellipse of minimum area that circumscribes 2 circles of equal radii that touch each other and found [this.](https://erich-friedman.github.io/packing/cirinel/)

 Here, we can clearly see that for a certain amount of equal circles, the circumscribing ellipse tends to circle. I tried to find a general formula for **n**, i.e. the number of such circles, but I am unable to start solving by taking ellipse equation as: 
*C* = $\dfrac{x^2}{a^2}+\dfrac{y^2}{b^2}=1$.
How should I take circle equation?

Comment: I can see only three circles on that page: for $n=1$, $n=7$ and $n=19$. It is not clear what you are asking.

Comment: I was asking a general formula. I edited now.

Comment: Packing problems are hard.  http://www.packomania.com/ shows the best known ways to pack circles into circles.  For certain numbers of circles the configuration is quite irregular.  Allowing the outer curve to be an ellipse just makes it harder by giving one more degree of freedom.